# Query to count the entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables like this.

```
A   B  
1   12  
2   13  
3   12  
4   13  
5   15  


B   C
12  APPLE  
13  ORANGE  
14  MANGO  
15  BANANA
```

I need output as below...

```
count(A)  B  C  
2         12 APPLE  
2         13 ORANGE  
0         14 MANGO  
1         15 BANANA
```

I have written the query using joins but I am stuck at displaying the count as zero in case of empty value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `left join` to get the values of `table2` even if there are no records for them in `table1`

```
select T2.B, T2.C, count(T1.A)
from table2 T2
left join table1 T1 on T1.B = T2.B
group by T2.B, T2.C
```

Comment: You forgot to add the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Am I the only person left who still likes to see `OUTER` specified in the join for completeness? I must be getting old and curmudgeonly or something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.A) as Cnt,T2.B,T2.C
FROM Table2 T2 LEFT JOIN
     Table1 T1 ON T1.B=T2.B
GROUP BY T2.B,T2.C
```

Result:

```
CNT   B     C
2     12    APPLE
1     15    BANANA
0     14    MANGO
2     13    ORANGE
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1846/8).

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you another option. You don't need a join, as you only want to show table2 records along with another value which you can get in a sub-query.

```
select (select count(*) from table1 where table1.B = table2.B) as cnt, B, C
from table2
order by B;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to do it (using subquery), but I would use this following one:

```
-- SETUP
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1 (A INT, B INT);
CREATE TABLE #TABLE2 (B INT, C CHAR(10));

INSERT #TABLE1
SELECT 1, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 15

INSERT #TABLE2
SELECT 12, 'APPLE'  UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'ORANGE' UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'MANGO'  UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'BANANA'

-- query
SELECT COUNT(qty.A), dsc.B, dsc.C
FROM      #TABLE2 dsc
LEFT JOIN #TABLE1 qty ON (dsc.B = qty.B)
GROUP BY dsc.B, dsc.C
ORDER BY dsc.B, dsc.C;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (A INT,  B INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE1 VALUES  
(1,   12),  
(2,   13),  
(3,   12),  
(4,   13),  
(5,   15)  

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (B INT,  C VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 VALUES  
(12,'APPLE'),  
(13,'ORANGE'),  
(14,'MANGO'),  
(15,'BANANA')




SELECT t2.C
       ,ISNULL(COUNT(t1.B), 0) total_Count
FROM @TABLE2 t2 LEFT JOIN @TABLE1 t1
ON t2.B = t1.B
GROUP BY t2.C   


C      total_Count
APPLE   2
BANANA  1
MANGO   0
ORANGE  2
```